# Configuring a mail driver in Laravel (using MAMP)

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to use Laravel's auth package, and I'm getting various errors when trying to use its "send password reset link" option. I'm using MAMP as the server. My .env by default looks like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I keep getting Swift_TransportException errors when I try to send mail.

Am I supposed to connect a Gmail address I own, using my email and password, essentially telling Laravel to use Gmail as the mail server? Isn't this a security risk since my password would be out in the open?

As an alternative, can/should I add a mail server to MAMP and use its credentials? Again, isn't that a security risk?

Comment: The question is less about specific errors and more about best practices. Allow "less secure apps" or a two-step verification app password in Gmail, for example. Or set up an alternate mail server?

Comment: The contents of `.env` won't be "out in the open". You can use Gmail for this in testing, but it's better to use something like Sendgrid or Amazon SES in production. Again, in any of these cases, your credentials don't show to visitors to the app unless you've done something dumb like print out the contents of `config()` to the browser somewhere.

Comment: You are getting that error because Mailtrap.io requires you to create a free account and they will give you credentials. If you decide to use [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead) instead of MAMP it includes [MailHog](https://laravel-news.com/homestead-now-includes-mailhog) as a dummy email server complete with a gui inbox ui.

Answer (score 1):

1. This configuration will save emails to log file:

   ```
   MAIL_DRIVER=log
   MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
   MAIL_PORT=587
   MAIL_USERNAME=null
   MAIL_PASSWORD=null
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
   ```
2. If you register in Sendgrid, you will be able to use their smtp server. 
   This configuration will use Sendgrid as smtp Server:

   ```
    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=your_user_name_from_sendgrid
    MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password_from_password
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
   ```

Comment: This sort of works, but as expected, the email is being dumped to laravel.log. How does one send it to an actual email account?

Comment: try to use sendgrid. it is really easy.

Comment: It is dumped to the laravel.log because setting `MAIL_DRIVER=log` causes the rest of the mail configuration to be ignored as the log driver does not need credentials

Comment: @staskrak it's still not working, added the sendgrid configuration and getting a 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""' error.